# wifi hardblocked acer aspire E1-572

Tags: networking, acer

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my machine "acer aspire e1-572" WiFi worked right after the installation, but now it says Wireless adapter is hard blocked.
here is the output of command

```
  $ sudo rfkill list
  0: phy0: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: yes
```

I had tried the following to remove hard unblock.
Added `blacklist acer-wmi` and `blacklist acer_wmi` to my `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.
but it is not working.
any other suggestions please?
Thanks

Comment: That usually means you've physically turned off the wireless. It's a button, or combination of buttons (sometimes involving Fn) that you pressed and disabled wireless. You need to turn it back on.

Comment: Yes its Fn+f3 but it is not responding its just showing the airplane icon not swithing wifi back.